# How to change a value in a table with already fulfilled values?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table in which there are 13 columns. From these 13 columns I need to replace a previous value with the updated one which is in line 11.

```
if (Integer.parseInt(res.getString("res_id")) == res_id) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(res.getString("rem_pay")) > 0) {
        String a = res.getString("rem_pay");
        System.out.println("You need to pay the remaining amount: " + a);
        System.out.println("How much you want to pay?");
        amount=scanner.nextDouble();
        String query1= "INSERT INTO reservations values()"; //Changing the old rem_pay with the new one which the variable amount
        amount=Double.parseDouble(res.getString("rem_pay"))-amount;
```

Any answer will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the table like this:

```
amount = Double.parseDouble(res.getString("rem_pay"))-amount;
String query1 = "UPDATE reservations SET amount=?";
PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
pStatement.setDouble(1, amount);
pstm.executeUpdate();
```